# Withdraw more than 2.5 million rupees in Indonesia, possible?

Tags: money, payment-cards, indonesia

It seems impossible to withdraw more than 2.5 million rupees at a time for some reason.

Is this correct?

If yes, why is that!?

Comment: Every ATM in the world has a limit of some kind, either the hard limit of cash on hand, or a regulatory soft limit. The soft limit is (usually) determined by the bank, and is meant to protect both the bank and customer from loss. If you need more than the daily soft limit, you would need to go to a bank branch (not necessarily your own bank chain) and withdraw what you want (up to your account limit) and pay any fees. You can also use a debit/credit card and request a cash advance.

Comment: @CGCampbell actually, the same ATM usually allows you to withdraw several times in a row. So I wasn't sure what the logic was as it did not seem to be anything related to protecting me or the bank. The "physical" limit on the number of bank notes given as explained in the answer below does make more sense.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Indonesian ATMs generally won't let you withdraw more than 25 banknotes at a time.  Since the largest denomination is only Rp. 100,000, this means 25 x 100k = 2.5 million.  See eg. the [Bank Mandiri FAQ](http://www.bankmandiri.co.id/english/article/faq-am.aspx).

It's worth remembering that there are parts of Indonesia where the [legal minimum wage](http://www.wageindicator.org/main/salary/minimum-wage/indonesia) barely crosses 1 million per month, not to mention all the people in the unofficial economy who earn even less, so that 2.5M is actually quite a large amount in local terms.

Comment: +1 for also putting things in perspective with the info on the minimum wage in Indonesia.

Comment: ATMs the world around usually limit cash to 20 - 25 notes maximum, as there are physical limits on how many notes the counting mechanism can accommodate.  The thicker the paper of the country's note, the less notes the machine can dispense.